# Ambigous args when sourcing another bash file in a bash file

Tags: bash

I create a bash file test.sh. The content of this bash is like below:

```
#!/bin/bash
#source another file
export ICS_START=/rdrive/ics/itools/unx/bin/
source $ICS_START/icssetup.sh

XMAIN=false
MAINLINE=false
STARTDIR=${PWD}

# Get args.
usage() {
  echo "Usage: $0 [-t <timestamp>] [-m] [-x]"
  exit 1
}
parse_args(){
  while getopts "ht:mx" OPT; do
    case $OPT in
      t) DATE=${OPTARG};;
      m) MAINLINE=true;;
      x) XMAIN=true;;
      h) usage;;
      ?) usage;;
    esac
  done
}
echo "$@"
parse_args "$@"
#other commands
myrun -d xxx -p xxx --time xxxx
```

I run this bash file with `./test.sh -t xxx -m -x`

During this process,the second source command is affected by the args `-t xxx -m -x`, it always throw errors as :
*Ambigous switch. Please use more characters.* I think icssetup.sh also define these args so we have conflicts with each other. How could I avoid this without changing arg characters?

I checked that the first two lines(source command) and the parse_args can both work well separately.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something that happens with bash but not other shells. The arguments of your script are passed to any sourced script.

A simple example showing this:

**test.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

source source.sh
echo Original Script: $# : $@
```

**source.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Sourced Script $# : $@
```

When you run test.sh, you see that even if no arguments are passed to the sourced script, it actually receives the original script arguments:

```
# ./test.sh a b
Sourced Script 2 : a b
Original script: 2 : a b
```

If you're attempting to pass no arguments to the sourced script, you might try to force it like:

```
source $ICS_START/icssetup.sh ""
```